# Concatenating triple quoted strings in python

Tags: python

What is the best way to concatenate two triple quoted strings in python?

Example:

```
varA= """INSERT ....... """
VarB= """SELECT.......""""
```

Desired Final Query =

```
  """INSERT........
     SELECT........"""
```

When I do :

```
varC=varA+varB
```

I get something like :

```
      """INSERT........

SELECT........"""
```

That is, I don't get the style I desire. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why does the indentation matter in the least? It's _entirely irrelevant_. Are you printing the SQL inline with Python code? How / why? If you're just sending it to your database server the indentation doesn't matter. (Note that the indentation in the first line isn't in the SQL query; it's in the surrounding Python code.)

Comment: print '{}\n{}'.format(varA, VarB)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using print() to show varC?
Try this,

```
varA = """INSERT ....... """

varB = """SELECT......."""

varC = varA + '\n' + varB

print(varC)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python the main use of triple quotes strings are for multiline strings. Thus `str1="bees"` is equivalent to `str1="""bees"""`, but

```
str1="""
   bees"""
```

is not equivalent to

```
str1="
   bees"
```

Anyway, using your two strings, if you just want to have str2 under str1, you can:

```
str1 = """INSERT......."""
str2 = """SELECT......."""

str3 = str1 + "\n" + str2

# >>> str1 = """INSERT......."""
# >>> str2 = """SELECT......."""
# >>> print str1 + "\n" + str2
# INSERT.......
# SELECT.......
```

or

```
print "{0}\n{1}".format(str1, str2)
```